# History of various definitions of topology

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, terminology, math-history

This question is not actually a serious mathematical one. I have been reading *Point Set Topology* for a while, and turns out that there are various possible ways to define a topology. Most popular one is using open set axioms. Another one is using closure axioms, which was introduced by Kuratowski.

I am interested to know name of the researchers who had given the definition of topological spaces in the following ways:

1. Definition through Open sets (The most popular one)
2. Definition through neighbourhood system
3. Definition through interior points

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) is a more appropriate venue for this question?

Comment: There is a book on these kind of questions : the Handbook of the History of General Topology", which answers all those questions ([publisher link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792344797)). Go find it in a good library.

Answer (score 2):

From "[The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points
in analysis and topology](http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/Sources/Moore-topology.pdf)" [PDF], by Gregory H. Moore:

> The idea of an open set in an abstract space (as opposed to n-dimensional Euclidean space, where the idea was
>   due to Baire and Lebesgue) was originated by Felix Hausdorff in the context of his topological spaces. However,
>   what Hausdorff called a topological space is a more specialized idea than what is now universally called a topological
>   space. What he used as a primitive idea is “neighborhood of a point.” ... Immediately after giving his axioms for a topological space, Hausdorff defined what he meant by an “interior
>   point” of a subset A of a topological space. Namely, x is an interior point of A if some neighborhood of x is a subset
>   of A. And x was said to be a boundary point of A if x belongs to A but is not an interior point of A. Then a set A
>   was defined to be an open set (“Gebiet”) if all of its points are interior points [1914, 214–215].

Comment: In the monumental General Topology by R. Engelking, at the end of many sections there is a "Historical Notes And Bibliography"  citing original sources, which are assembled in a thorough index of references.